# SAML SSO with Node and Angular 2+

Tags: node.js, angular, single-sign-on, saml, passport-saml

The system I am working with is made in PHP, and I was asked to upgrade it to a Node and Angular based System.

The credentials are dealt with SAML with ADFS Service using SSO.

Since this stuff works with sessions any work around when working with Angular2+ and NodeJs, I tried using passport-saml and seems to make the Node part work, but it doesn't authenticate when adding the Angular HTTP calls.

Besides, how to get groups and info from the ADFS?

Comment: Are you passing the cookie (assuming you're using an Http-Only cookie from your SAML response) back in your Angular requests? Angular won't add `withCredentials` to your requests unless you tell it to do so.

Comment: I tried adding with Credentiales true in the header, some CORS errors started to appear,  but  apparently are from the Idp , not able to modified the idp myself , is there any work around?

Comment: The only SAML-based authentication I've done with Angular is via Okta, which sets an Http-Only cookie on return from a successful authentication. After that, the cookie is passed back on every subsequent request by overriding the default request options. Do you have a similar setup?